# WCF HttpException "There was no channel actively listening" dropping from Windows Application Event Log

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

We are dropping some legacy WCF interface endpoints from our API (under IIS 7.5). During that process, I noticed that the windows event log was recording some errors about it. For example, the interface IDontExistAnyLonger results in an eventlog entry:

[image]

I thought I could simply hook into the Global.asax.cs and capture / clear those events... but what I found is the event is actually inserted into the Application event log BEFORE Application_Error is even called.

Digging around, I thought maybe a web.config could remove this, but no success with that yet.

I continued digging around the Microsoft reference source, and it appears that the event is bubbled up and captured at the HostedHttpRequestAsync.End method:

[Microsoft Reference Source of End()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Activation/System/ServiceModel/Activation/HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.cs,848b21bc6e14ef6a,references)

Looking at the reference source, it doesn't look like there is a way to prevent that from being called, but I am hoping I am just misunderstanding the process and this can be accomplished.

Any thoughts or ideas on how I can prevent those kinds of messages from entering my EventLog?

.net 4.5.2
.64 bit process